# Selenium WebDriver exception unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32000,"message":"Promise was collected"}

Tags: python, selenium

When I use Selenium to do some web automation work, I get this error once in three runs. I searched everywhere on Google and could not find any information, could you please help?
 The code in question is:

```py
driver.get("https://www.baidu.com")
kw = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'kw'))) 
kw.send_keys('keyword')
su = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,'su')))
su.click()
content = WebDriverWait(driver,100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[id=\"content_left\"]")))
search_res = content.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'result')
    for res in search_res:
        links = res.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
        url = links[-1].get_attribute('href')
```

I tried to replace the `function presence_of_element_located()` with `find_element()` but no luck.
I am using:

- Windows10,
- python3.10,
- Selenium v4.2

I tried the code with various browsers like chrome96, 97,98,105; edge version 106, still same error, Can any one help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm us the url of the page you are scraping? Also, can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Pls post your code what you've tried

Comment: I am using the code to check my rankings on baidu.com, when I go to certain pages to find all 10 entries, the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

It seems few people run into this problem, and I have not fixed it yet. So I simply use try except to ignore it and meanwhile get another python script constantly running in the background to monitor it. So far so good.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).